# FIrebase FCM - push message ends up in wrong app

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to deliver push messages to may iOS apps. 
My FCM setup consists of a single Firebase project with multiple Firebase apps:

```
FB Project
  App1 Android
  App1 iOS
  App2 Android
  App2 iOS
  ...
```

Now the problem is that a FCM message sent to one of my iOS apps ends up being received by *another* iOS app (Send to App1 iOS - App2 iOS gets the message).

To debug the issue I have followed this excellent debugging guide: 
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html

I found out that:

1. delivering messages directly via APNS works fine (see section 4)
2. delivering messages via FCM with cURL (section 5) sends the message to a random app.

I then realised that both of my client apps on my device have *identical* firebase device tokens. So Firebase does not appear to differentiate apps on a token level.
Still I would have expected the message would be received by *all* of my iOS instead of a random one.

**Question 1: Is that the expected behaviour of Firebase?**

Now in the real app I target the different apps by registering to different channels, prefixing an app identifier like that:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/app1-news"]]; 
}
```

Sending to that channel produces random results including:

- message received by the intended (App1)
- message received by another app (e.g. App2)
- message received by multiple apps (App1, App2, ...)
- message received multiple times by one app (App2, App2)
- message not received at all

**Question 2: How can I get this right?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the expected behavior. FCM tokens are stored in the keychain with Authorized Entity (same for entire firebase project), and scope (generally "*"). However, the keychain is storing them based on the app's bundle identifier, which should separate them from each other.

Sanity check: Are you using different GoogleService-Info.plist files for each iOS app?

Also, are you using shared keychain access groups? Is the shared keychain access group at the top of the list in `keychain-access-groups` in your entitlements? That would explain how the SDK is accidentally finding the FCM token for the other app. In the [documentation for Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-SW1):

> When your app creates a keychain item, if you do not explicitly specify the `kSecAttrAccessGroup` key in the item’s attributes dictionary, Keychain Services uses the first group of the app’s access groups array (ordered as shown above) as the default access group. If your app has a `keychain-access-groups` entitlement, Keychain Services uses the first of these. Otherwise, it uses the application identifier, which is always present. Thus, by default, unless you add a `keychain-access-groups` entitlement, an app creates keychain items to which only it has access.

The SDK determines the "default access group" by attempting to create a small keychain item and looking at the access group (the first in the `keychain-access-groups` list is the default). Typically with keychain access groups, you want to have the app's application-identifier as the first item, followed by any shared groups. That way, unless otherwise specified, your keychain items are written to the individual app, unless explicitly stored in a shared access group.

Comment: Thanks, keychain was the keyword!I added keychain sharing as a workaround for to the problem described here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/ios-10-xcode-8-and-swift-3.html . After disabling shared keychain push messages work as expected!